# How can I use test database for intern testing

Tags: intern

I am using intern for testing in my node project, however I don't know how to set up the intern properly so that it uses 'test' database instead of 'development' database. I was trying to put the code `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'` into my test file, but it doesn't work. My `intern.js` file is just the default file and my intern running command is `/node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/intern`. All the test run properly except the data was generated in the development database not the test database. Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you!

---

Here is one of my test case in my test suite, which add the data to the database

```
tdd.test('normal user creation', function(){
  var name = chance.name();
  return models.User.create({
    name: name,
    gender: chance.gender(),
    email: chance.email(),
    balance: 0.0,
    phone_number: chance.phone({country: 'ca', mobile: true})
  }).then(function (user) {
    return assert.strictEqual(name, user.name, 'user name should ' +
      'be equal to each other');
  }).catch(function (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you post a little code where the data added to the database?

Comment: @kpie I have posted my code, thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure : /

Comment: What database are you using and how are you starting it up? How does an application in your environment normally decide which database to use?

Comment: @jason0x43 I use MySQL for the database, normally the testing framework should use the test database automatically. When I use mocha testing framework, it will use the test database automatically.

Comment: What does the code look like where you're making your database connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. In the `package.json` file, set the `scripts` option as

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node src/index.js",
  "test": "set NODE_ENV=test&&intern-client config=tests/intern"
},
```

then run `npm test`, the intern will run the test base on test database now